# virtualbox guest os server

Tags: ubuntu, networking, virtualbox

I'm playing around with some web development and I'm doing most of the work on a ubuntu guest os running in virtualbox on windows. The networking modes are really confusing and all I want to do is access the http server running in the guest os from the host. Is there a simple way to do this without setting up port forwarding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just configure the guest host to use the bridged networking mode and the guest will be accessible on the network as a regular host.