# Accessing guest OS server from Host in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu-11.04

I have Ubuntu installed in VirtualBox on my windows machine with the default setup.  I can visit my apache server in the guest OS by going to localhost:8080, but can't access it from the host (windows) by ip address specified in ifconfig.
    My network setting is bridged networking mode as per [virtualbox guest os server](https://superuser.com/questions/162689/virtualbox-guest-os-server)

**Update**
subnet are the same.  Windows firewall is disabled.

Comment: Are your Ubuntu VM and Windows Host machine on the same subnet?

Comment: Does your guest OS allow connections through its firewall to port 8080?

Comment: Please be more specific asking your questions. How are your trying to access from host?

Comment: What I ment was that the ubuntu will also have a firewall. Is it configured properly? This has nothing to do with your Windows firewall.

Answer (score 0):

What is the network connection?

Have you tried using bridged network type?

or Host only type?

This should help you gain an ip address from the router and with this you should be able to access it from your host machine.